# Django ListView pagination setting up

Tags: django, listview, pagination, customization

Am I able to customize pagination process of ListView? For instance, I'd like to catch some `Exception` suxh a `ValueError` in case of we sent not numerable string. Or I just need to overwrite `paginate_queryset` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try something like this :

```
page = request.GET.get('page')
paginator = Paginator(blogs, 10)
try:
    blogs = paginator.page(page)
except PageNotAnInteger:
    blogs = paginator.page(1)
except EmptyPage:
    blogs = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
```

source: https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/50824/django.core.paginator.EmptyPage